# Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG

Tags: sql-server-2008

Good Evening to all.

I was working with sql server 2008.

Thing i did:

Actually i was noticed that the free space available in C drive reaches below 1 GB .So i thought to Club the D drive with C drive.I had extended the C drive to 18 GB.

Error that Occurs:

Once i finish Extending the drive size i restarted my system.After logon i opened the Microsoft Sql server Management Studio which has multiple database.Every thing works fine except the Database which i have worked recently.When try to expand the table it shows the error as
"**

> Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG. A severe error
>   occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be
>   discarded. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

**"
This is how i runned the DBCC runcheck catalog:

> DBCC CHECKDB (Demo) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS

and this is the error which i get while running the above:

> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.

Can any one please help me tocome out of this rid.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try on http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Ok thanks for the referral let me try out there

Comment: Execute DBCC CHECKDB, DBCC CHECKTABLE. Please tell me the results.